# How to LISTEN/GET for updated data to send to subscribed websocket clients using FastAPI

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi

I can't find the exact guide of what I want to do, it's more of a structural and architectural issue:

Tooling:

- Python 3.9
- FastAPI
- Uvicorn
- Some scripts to monitor the folders
- It'll run under docker when its done

The exact task:
I want to build a web-app that lists the photos in a directory and shows them in a grid in the browser.
The key points here:

- It will use **watchdog** to immediately get any added or removed items.
- Clients will connect with a web socket (I've followed those tutorials)
- ***Deltas will be send to observing clients***

The last bit is my issue, and to the point of the question:
What is a "accepted/best practice" for having my watchdog script send the added/removed items to the connected client web sockets.

I can't for the life of me work out how they communicate, running in uvicorn I just can't start an arbitrary background job.... I know in a dev environment I can start uvicorn manually, but I want it to follow scalable patterns even if it's just for light usage.

In short: **How can a listening python script inform my fastAPI there's new data**

The easy/obvious answer is to expose a management API that the wathcdog script can send... but is there any sort of message bus that fastAPI can listen to?

AWSGI is new to me, I have some experience with python async/scheduler, but have mostly used WSGI frameworks like Bottle where scheduling/threading isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, unless anyone has any amazing ideas, the best solution is:

Connect to REDIS, pull existing values at the time the client web socket connects.

The worker process(es) can push new values via REDIS.

Since the connected client handler can use asyncio, they can subscribe to the pub/sun model.

Problem solved, yes it requires REDIS but that’s easy enough in docker.

Why REDIS?

Low boiler plate code needed, full pub/sub support and low setup pain.